# How to use JSON object internally rather than an external file in HTML

Tags: jquery, html

I currently have an external JSON file data.json and I want to know how to instead of calling on this external file, have the data stored within the html code.

The purpose of this code is for a dynamic dropdown.

This is my JSON data within data.json

```
{
    "beverages": "Coffee,Coke",
    "snacks": "Chips,Cookies"
}
```

This is my JQUERY

```
    $("#first-choice").change(function() {

    var $dropdown = $(this);

    $.getJSON("jsondata/data.json", function(data) {

        var key = $dropdown.val();
        var vals = [];

        switch(key) {
            case 'beverages':
                vals = data.beverages.split(",");
                break;
            case 'snacks':
                vals = data.snacks.split(",");
                break;
            case 'base':
                vals = ['Please choose from above'];
        }

        var $secondChoice = $("#second-choice");
        $secondChoice.empty();
        $.each(vals, function(index, value) {
            $secondChoice.append("<option>" + value + "</option>");
        });
    });
});
```

So instead of using .getJSON to call on the external file, I would like the data to be stored there. And how would I then need to alter the code following?

Comment: I'm not sure to understand well your question. Do you want the json being hardcoded directly? `let MyData = { beverages: "Coffee,Coke", snacks: "Chips,Cookies" };` ?

Answer (score 2):

Simply assign this JSON (*JavaScript Object Notation*) to variable and use that var later:

```
var data = {
    "beverages": "Coffee,Coke",
    "snacks": "Chips,Cookies"
}
```

---

Your final code would be:

```
$("#first-choice").change(function() {
    var $dropdown = $(this);
    var data = {
        "beverages": "Coffee,Coke",
        "snacks": "Chips,Cookies"
    }
    var key = $dropdown.val();
    var vals = [];

    switch(key) {
        case 'beverages':
            vals = data.beverages.split(",");
            break;
        case 'snacks':
            vals = data.snacks.split(",");
            break;
        case 'base':
            vals = ['Please choose from above'];
    }

    var $secondChoice = $("#second-choice");
    $secondChoice.empty();

    $.each(vals, function(index, value) {
        $secondChoice.append("<option>" + value + "</option>");
    });
});
```

Comment: I understand this but i'm not sure where to put that code and what part of the current code i need to remove and what parts i need to alter. Thank you

Comment: This will only work if the Javascript is inline, rather than being in a separate file.

Comment: @CertainPerformance So OP is asking how to store JSON inline with JS code.

Comment: That doesn't seem to be certain, given that we haven't seen the HTML

Answer (score 1):

If your Javascript is in an inline script tag, rather than on an external page, just paste in the JSON into a variable:

```
const data = {
  "beverages": "Coffee,Coke",
  "snacks": "Chips,Cookies"
};
$("#first-choice").change(function() {
  var $dropdown = $(this);
  var key = $dropdown.val();
  // etc
```

But inline Javascript is a bit inelegant and requires more data to be sent over the wire every time the page is requested - storing the JS in an external file that can be cached is often a good idea.

If that's what you're doing (or if that's what you want to do), if your Javascript is linked to in the `src` of a script tag, then you'll have to use another method. One is to put the JSON inside a `<script>` tag with a `type` *other* than one parsed as Javascript (to ensure it doesn't try to run and encounter script errors): for example, you can use `type="application/json"`, then select the tag, and parse its `textContent`:

```js
const json = document.querySelector('#data').textContent;
const data = JSON.parse(json);
// etc
console.log(data);
```

```html
<script type="application/json" id="data">
{
  "beverages": "Coffee,Coke",
  "snacks": "Chips,Cookies"
}
</script>
```

A third option is to store it in a `data-` attribute of a tag, rather than in the `textContent` of a tag:

```js
const json = document.querySelector('[data-json]').dataset.json;
const data = JSON.parse(json);
// etc
console.log(data);
```

```html
<script
  src="linkToYourJs"
  data-json='{"beverages": "Coffee,Coke","snacks": "Chips,Cookies"}'
></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Why not inline the variable instead of loading from the file?**

---

Modified script

```js
$(function() {

// Hide 2nd dropdown on document.ready
$('#second-choice').hide();

$("#first-choice").change(function() {

  var $dropdown = $(this);

  // Inlined variable instead of making a AJAX request to read it from a file!
  const data = {
    "beverages": "Coffee,Coke",
    "snacks": "Chips,Cookies"
  };

  var key = $dropdown.val();
  var vals = [];

  switch (key) {
    case 'beverages':
   vals = data.beverages.split(",");
   break;
    case 'snacks':
   vals = data.snacks.split(",");
   break;
    case 'base':
   vals = ['Please choose from above'];
  }

  var $secondChoice = $("#second-choice");
  $secondChoice.empty();
  $.each(vals, function(index, value) {
    $secondChoice.append("<option>" + value + "</option>");
  });
    // Show 2nd dropdown now
    $('#second-choice').show();
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="first-choice">
  <option selected disabled>----Please select an option----</option>
  <option value="beverages">Beverages</option>
  <option value="snacks">Snacks</option>
</select>

<select id="second-choice">
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well it's arguably not ideal to do what you're describing. Muddying your HTML with data is not the prettiest solution. That said, the solution would be to store the JSON as a JS object:

```
<script>
data = {"myjson": "here"};
</script>
```

Then in your script everything stays the same except you no longer wrap the code in an AJAX request.